# Remove whitespace from within a regex capturing group

Tags: regex

This should be a simple job, but this morning I just can't seem to find the answer I need

Value:

```
N.123456 7
```

Current regex

```
N.(\d{6}\s?\d)
```

Returns single matching group

```
123456 7
```

Want it to return single matching group

```
1234567
```

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to match discontinuous texts within one match operation. To remove matches, use a regex replace method/function. Or, capture into 2 groups (e.g. with `N.(\d{6})\s?(\d)`) and then join the values after a match is found. And a note: to match a literal `.` you should escape `.` in your pattern.

Comment: You could remove all whitespace before performing the regex

Comment: So you mean you want `N\.(\d{6})\s?\d`?

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to remove the whitespace before processing. I just need to return the 7 numbers only. I can easily do it in code later, but I would really like to be able to strip it out from the regex matching group itself if possible.

Comment: No revo, I need all 7 numbers

Comment: Considering seventh digit, you need to capture second part like in `N\.(\d{6})\s?(\d)` then work with back-references `\1\2`.

Comment: @revo, he wants to concatenate the result, how will he do it?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod No way other than my last comment or with help of a replace functionality.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just have to do a string replace in code after getting the group matchers then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return as single matching group. I think what are you looking for is non-capturing group (?: ).

There is explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

Maybe this regex would help you. It will exclude space character with non capturing group.

```
N.(\d{6})(?:\s?)(\d)
```

It will capture `123456` in group 1 and `7` in group 2.

What you want is probably this. It will return `1234567`

```
"N.123456 7".replaceAll("N.(\\d{6})(?:\\s?)(\\d)", "$1$2")
```

Comment: I didn't refresh page to see comments. I add solution at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d+)
```

This should work.